# How to locate particular tags under a specific id using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
<div id="was-price">
   <div class="price">
      <div class="value-price-badge__Special-Buy price-format__badge price-format__badge-align"></div>
      <div class="price-format__large price-format__main-price">
          <span class="price-format__large-symbols">$</span>
          <span>509</span>
          <span class="price-format__large-symbols">40</span>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I am trying to locate all the **span** elements under the **div** with id=was-price. I tried this way: `driver.find_element_by_id('was-price').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'span').` and this did not work.

What is the right way to locate these span elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
driver.find_element_by_id('was-price').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'span')
```

should work if you want to locate single `span` node. If you want to get list try

```
driver.find_element_by_id('was-price').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'span')
```

You can also try XPath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="was-price"]//span')
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to mentioned by JaSON you can locate all these elements with single css_selector as following:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#was-price span')
```